# LiteDB.LiteException: File is not a valid LiteDB database format or contains a invalid password

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, litedb

Using LiteDB for my Xamarin.android project. Just updated the nuget package to 5.0.9 and this error occurs.

> LiteDB.LiteException: File is not a valid LiteDB database format or contains a invalid password.

Comment: What is your string connection? Try to add `upgrade = true` in yoru connection string. And this issue has opened on Github. You could follow this. https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/1428 If it does not matter, do not upgrate the nuget package to 5.0.9 and use the older version.